# Is it possible to split the training DataLoader (and dataset) into training and validation datasets?

Tags: python, pytorch, torch

The torchvision package provides easy access to commonly used datasets. [You would use them like this](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/blitz/cifar10_tutorial.html#sphx-glr-beginner-blitz-cifar10-tutorial-py):

```
trainset = torchvision.datasets.CIFAR10(root='./data', train=True,
                                        download=True, transform=transform)
trainloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(trainset, batch_size=4,
                                          shuffle=True, num_workers=2)

testset = torchvision.datasets.CIFAR10(root='./data', train=False,
                                       download=True, transform=transform)
testloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(testset, batch_size=4,
                                         shuffle=False, num_workers=2)
```

Apparently, you can only switch between `train=True` and `train=False`. The [docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/torchvision/datasets.html#torchvision.datasets.MNIST) explain:

> train (bool, optional) – If True, creates dataset from training.pt,
>   otherwise from test.pt.

But this goes against the common practice of having a three-way split. For serious work, I need another `DataLoader` with a validation set. Also, it would be nice to specify the split proportions myself. They don't say what percentage of the dataset is reserved for testing, maybe I would like to change that.

I assume that this is a conscious design decision. Everyone working on one of these datasets is supposed to use the same testset. That makes results comparable. But I still need to get a validation set out of the `trainloader`. Is it possible to split a `DataLoader` into two separate streams of data?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Meanwhile, I stumbled upon the method [`random_split`](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/data.html#torch.utils.data.random_split). So, you don't split the `DataLoader`, but you split the `Dataset`:

```
torch.utils.data.random_split(dataset, lengths)
```